# Can the scalar curvature remain locally constant under the action of the Ricci flow?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, ricci-flow

Disclaimer: I know close to nothing about differential geometry, only basics due to my early interest in general relativity when I was in high school almost 20 years ago. Therefore the present question would probably not be relevant for MathOverflow, and that's why I'm asking it here.

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold of dimension at least two. Under which hypotheses can one be sure that at least one point thereof has the same scalar curvature when a Ricci flow is performed during the whole process?
Many thanks in advance and sorry is this question ever turns out to make no sense.

Comment: Can you make your question more precise? If we talk about the curvature as a function $R(x,t)$ (where $x \in M$ and $t$ is the time in the flow), do you mean that for a particular $x_0$ we have $R(x_0,t)$ constant in $t$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: I think $S^2$ with metric induced by $R^3$is a example that scalar cuvature keeps constant under Ricci flow.